# How to remove element and avoid the error "adding element with duplicate id" when reinserting with same ID?

Tags: sapui5

I want to remove all content of a page and insert different content into it with a click of a button.

Unfortunately some of the content is the same and therefore has the same id.
I expected it to not be a problem because I never try to insert the same element twice. I want to remove it before reinserting it again.

But apparently the methods I found: `oPage.removeAllContent();` and `oPage.destroyContent();` don't actually remove the old content completely because I'm still getting the error that I'm trying to add an element with a duplicate id:
`Error: adding element with duplicate id 'text'`

How can I remove the old content so that the old ids are actually forgotten and I can reinsert them?

Here's a minimal example (click the `Reload` button twice and on the second time the error will appear in the console):
https://jsfiddle.net/1Lqc36uh/

Here's the most relevant (I think) part:

```js
let oPage = this.byId(this.detailId);
oPage.removeAllContent();
oPage.destroyContent();
if (bSetText) {
    oPage.insertContent(new sap.m.Text(this.textId, {
        text: "SetText"
    }));
} else {
    oPage.insertContent(new sap.m.Text(this.textId, {
        text: "Test"
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the line `oPage.removeAllContent();`.

The issue is that you're removing the content **and then** trying to destroy it:

> ```js
> oPage.removeAllContent(); // removes the existing content (without destroying it).
> oPage.destroyContent(); // tries to destroy but there is no content!
> ```

The ManagedObject method `destroyXYZ()` relies on the fact that the child controls exist as part of the aggregation in the first place.
Removing the controls by `removeAllXYZ()` does remove them from the UI and makes them no longer related to the parent, but they're not destroyed and still in the control registry. Hence, the "duplicate ID" error.

The method `destroyContent()` is sufficient to remove the content from the UI **and** from the control registry.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to give each element an ID? Most things can be done without an ID in UI5. Usually a `JSONModel` is the better approach to control UI elements.

For example you can make the first element visible and the second invisible (even using the same property in the JSONModel so both elements are automatically toggled).

That being said you can destroy the removed elements themself.

```js
oPage
    .removeAllContent()
    .forEach(oControl => { oControl.destroy(); });
```

---

Edit: You can unaccept this answer, seems like @Boghyon gave a better one.