# What is the difference between destroySteps() and removeAllSteps() in SAP UI5?

Tags: sapui5

I wanted to do something with a Wizard in SAP UI5 and came across those two methods. When looking a the method description of the documentation, the description has the same meaning (to me):
[image: removeAllSteps]
[image: destroySteps]

Where is the difference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71131717/5846045