# how to avoid 'adding element with duplicate id '__component0---join--searchInput' - ' error in this code

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```
    <VBox class= "outerHorizon">
                <Button text="search" press=".openModal"/>
            </VBox>
```

it is this code to call a modal view.

I want to change the screen contents in modal state.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "tips/logis/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/core/ValueState",
    "tips/common/util/Validator",
    "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
], function(BaseController, JSONModel, ValueState, Validator, Fragment) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("tips.logis.controller.contents.demo.Join", {
        
        onInit: function(){
            window.join = this;
            this._dialog = null;
            this.setModel(new JSONModel(), "userModel");
        },
        openModal: function () {
            let that = this;
            let oView = this.getView();
            //"tips.logis.view.fragment.Dialog"
            if (!this._dialog) {
                this._dialog = this.loadFragment("tips.logis.view.fragment.Dialog")
                .then((oDialog)=>{
                    oDialog.removeAllContent();
                    oDialog.destroyContent();
                    return that.loadFragment("tips.logis.view.fragment.SearchCompany")
                    .then((frgContent)=>{
                        oDialog.setTitle('search company');
                        oDialog.addContent(frgContent);
                        oDialog.open();
                        return oDialog;
                    });
                });
            } else {
                this._dialog.then(oDialog=>{
                    oDialog.removeAllContent();
                    oDialog.destroyContent();
                    return that.loadFragment("tips.logis.view.fragment.SearchCompany")
                    .then((frgContent)=>{
                        oDialog.setTitle('search company');
                        oDialog.removeAllContent();
                        oDialog.addContent(frgContent);
                        oView.addDepen
                        oDialog.open();
                        return oDialog;
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        changeContent: function() {
            var that = this;
            this._dialog.then(oDialog=>{
                return that.loadFragment("tips.logis.view.fragment.RegisterCompany")
                .then(frgContent=>{
                    oDialog.setTitle("register company");
                    oDialog.removeAllContent();
                    oDialog.addContent(frgContent);
                    return oDialog;
                });
            });
        },
        closeModal: function() {
            this._dialog.then(oDialog=>oDialog.close());
        },
        loadFragment: function(fileName) {
            return Fragment.load({
                id: this.getView().getId(),
                name: fileName,
                controller: this
            });
        },
        onAfterClose: function(oEv) {
            oEv.getSource().removeAllContent();
            oEv.getSource().destroyContent();
            oEv.getSource().destroy();        
        }
    });
}, true);
```

this is sap view controller.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
 <Dialog title="search company" afterClose="onAfterClose">
    <beginButton>
        <Button text="close" press="closeModal"></Button>
    </beginButton>
    <endButton>
        <Button text="adjust" press="onPressAdjust"></Button>
    </endButton>
</Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

this is dialog fragment view.

```
//SearchCompany.fragment
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:table="sap.ui.table" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<l:VerticalLayout class="container" width="600px">
    <FlexBox justifyContent = "Center">
        <Input width="300px" id="searchInput"/>
        <HBox>
            <Button text="Search" class="searchBtn"/>
            <Button text="Add" press="changeContent"/>
        </HBox>
    </FlexBox>
    <Table items="{/items}">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Column 1" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Column 2" />
        </Column>
        <!-- Add more columns as needed -->
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
            <Text text="{itemProperty1}" />
            <Text text="{itemProperty2}" />
            <!-- Add more cells for additional columns -->
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
    </Table>
</l:VerticalLayout>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:table="sap.ui.table" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<l:VerticalLayout class="container" width="600px">

    <Label text="Bizno" class="Label"/>
    <FlexBox justifyContent="SpaceAround" width="500px">
        <Input width="150px"/>
        <Input width="150px"/>
        <Input width="150px"/>
    </FlexBox>
    <HBox alignItems="Center" class="bizname">
        <Label text="BizName" class="bizname component"/>
        <Input class="bizname component"/>
        <Button  text="confirm" class="bizname component"/>
    </HBox>
    
</l:VerticalLayout>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

there are fragment codes for changing info view in the modal view.

if this codes run, The error below occurs.

I would like to ask how to resolve this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jdR9.png)

I want the view information to change in modal state.

Comment: You have the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/a/71131717/5846045